# How is this “continuity” condition called? (differentiation under the integral sign, Cramer-Rao)

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, statistics

I have seen a treatment of Fisher information and the Cramer-Rao bound, where a bunch of conditions were assumed and it was not always clear exactly why they are used in particular.

One of them has to do with differentiation under the integral sign and it looks like this:

> $$q_{\theta,\delta}(x) := 1_{\{\mathcal L(\theta,\_) > 0\}}(x)\cdot
>  \sup \{ \| l_\theta(x) - l_{\theta'}(x) \| : \theta' \in \Theta\text{
>  s.t. } \| \theta - \theta'\| < \delta\}$$ is such that there is a
>   $\delta > 0$ s.t. $\mathbb E_\theta(q_{\theta,\delta}(X)^2) < \infty$
>   for all $\theta\in\Theta$

(this is already the paraphrased version, the original looks imho more obscure). Here $\mathcal L$ is the likelihood function, $l$ the score function and $\_$ is a placeholder for an argument.

My question is whether this has a name (and where else it shows it up), because it is simply stated without any further motivation and frankly looks ad-hoc. I also wonder whether this has anything to do with the regularity conditions given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Statement).

([originally asked here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313205/how-is-this-continuity-condition-called-differentiation-under-the-integral-s))